# Do all airbag squibs on Opel Corsa C include steering angle sensor?

Tags: parts, vauxhall, opel, steering-wheel, supplemental-restraint-system

Do all the airbag squibs on an Opel/Vauxhall Corsa C include steering angle sensor? I mean is the steering angle sensor included in the part even on cars that do not have ESP/ESC (Electronic Stability Probram/Control)?

The most common part nr. I found is 24459850 1610662 although I think this part has multiple types (saw other nr. on same part too). The airbag squib looks like this:

Top view
[image]

Bottom view
[image]

Comment: That is a clock spring not a squib.

Comment: Yes various people call this differently - it surely is a clockspring too. However, the question remains - is there a steering angle sensor in it?